# What is the difference between indentation and pretty printing used in c++?

Tags: c++

Indentation and pretty printing are used to improve the clarity and readability of a program. Both these styles use spaces. And how can I distinguish between them.

Comment: no, indentation is used to format code. pretty printing is formatting OUTPUT from a program so it's easily readable.

Comment: Pretty printing is a mean to produce indented code. So I don't understand your question! Please edit it to improve it.

Comment: Indentation is a property of the code. Pretty printing is a process that transforms code. It's a bit like the difference between spices and cooking.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty Printing is a method used to make your code easily readable and understandable. In Wikipedia, Pretty Printing is explained as follows

> Prettyprint (or pretty-print) is the application of any of various
>   stylistic formatting conventions to text files, such as source code,
>   markup, and similar kinds of content. These formatting conventions can
>   adjust positioning and spacing (indent style), add color and contrast
>   (syntax highlighting), adjust size, and make similar modifications
>   intended to make the content easier for people to view, read, and
>   understand. Prettyprinters for programming language source code are
>   sometimes called code beautifiers or syntax highlighters.

Now lets see what Indentation is

> In the written form of many languages, an indentation is an empty
>   space at the beginning of a line to signal the start of a new
>   paragraph. Many computer languages have adopted this technique to
>   designate "paragraphs" or other logical blocks in the program.
>
> In computer programming languages, indentation is used to format
>   program source code to improve readability. Indentation is generally
>   only of use to programmers; compilers and interpreters rarely care how
>   much whitespace is present in between programming statements.

From these, one can understand that indentation is a way of Implementing Pretty Printing.